# How to rename collection which already exists in mongodb atlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB atlas named `callhistories` I want to rename it as `call_history`.
If I add the third option in my mongoose model as below :

```
const callHistory = mongoose.model("callHistory", callHistorySchema, 'call_history');
```

Would it rename my collection in MongoDB atlas or it will break my site?

Please Help..!

Comment: 'I think I got my answer.
please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878935/how-to-change-collection-name-in-mongoose-model"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do :

```
 mongoose.model('callHistory', callHistorySchema, 'call_history'); 
 //Here 3rd argument 'call_history': as collection name
```

you can also do :

```
let callHistorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: String.
  ....... 
}, { collection: 'call_history' });
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 6):

`db.callhistories.renameCollection('call_history')` use this to rename your existing collection 
and if you want to know more you can go to the official documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the renameCollection function of MongoDB to change the collection name.

for eg:-

```
const callHistory = mongoose.model('callHistory', callHistorySchema);
callHistory.renameCollection('call_history');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this if using mongodb nodejs driver:

```
db.collection(':podCasts').rename('podCasts');
```

The previous answers won't work if you have a special symbol (like above example) as your collection name.