# Status 201 on POST but Another Collection Created Instead of Using the Existing One

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

EDIT: My question is answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878935/how-to-change-collection-name-in-mongoose-model). I made the following changes in **Model.js** file:

```
const MyTodoList = mongoose.model("MyTodoList", MyTodoListSchema, 'colltodolist');
module.exports = MyTodoList;
```

I am trying to send POST request using POSTMAN to my backend which is running on **port 5035**. The post URL is http://localhost:5035/api/todos.

The problem is that I'm getting **STATUS: 201 Created** and the console is showing success, but a new collection was created instead of the updating the existing one.

My MongoDB collection is created on ATLAS and the structure looks like this:

**dbname: dbtodolist**

**collectioname: colltodolist**

When I sent the POST request, instead of updating the **colltodolist**, it added a new collection in db called **mytodolists**

The code in **index.js** is:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://sidrah:sidrah@cluster0.yidsza6.mongodb.net/dbtodolist?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
  .then(()=> {
    console.log('Database connected');
  })
  .catch((error)=> {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');
  });
```

Since the application follows MVC architecture, here is the remaining code:

**Model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MyTodoListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
todo: {
type: String,
default: "",
required: true
}
const MyTodoList = mongoose.model("MyTodoList", MyTodoListSchema);
module.exports = MyTodoList;
```

**Controller.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MyTodoList = require('../models/model');

exports.createTodo = (req, res) => {
  const todo = new MyTodoList({
     todo: req.body.todo
  });
  return todo
    .save()
    .then((newTodo) => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'New todo list created successfully',
        MyTodoList: newTodo,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server error. Please try again.',
        error: error.message,
      });
    });
}  

//get all todos
exports.getAllTodo = (req, res) => {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
      res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS" ); 
  MyTodoList.find()
    .select('taskId todo priority')
 ); 
    .then((allTodo) => {
      return res.status(200).json({
        Todo: allTodo
      });
      
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Server error. Please try again.',
        error: err.message,
      });
    });
  }
```

**Router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const todolist_controller = require('../controllers/controller')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/todos', todolist_controller.createTodo);
router.get('/todos', todolist_controller.getAllTodo);
module.exports = router;
```

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: If your backend is running on port 5035, why are you making a request to port 1337?

Comment: I figured this out and edited the question. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Yes, new collection is being created inside the same db.